# Using another object as parameter in Jmockit Mocked object

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I'm new to JMockit and have successfully run a basic unit test using it.  However, I'm stuck when attempting to mock a Spring LdapTemplate. The problem seems to be with the LdapQuery that is used by the LdapTemplate. Do I need to mock this as well?

JUnit Test

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mocked
    LdapTemplate mockLdapTemplate;

    @Test
    public void retrieveAccount_test() {

        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.setEmail("foobar@gmail.com");
        acct.setUserId("userA");
        final List<Account> expected = Arrays.asList(acct);

        new Expectations() {
            { 
              mockLdapTemplate.search(query().base(anyString).where(anyString)
                    .is("userA"), (AttributesMapper) any);
              result = expected;
            }
        };
        AccountService service = new AccountServiceImpl(mockLdapTemplate);
        Account account = service.retrieveAccount("userA");
        assertThat(account, is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

AccountService

```
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

@Autowired
public AccountServiceImpl(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
    this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
}

@Override
public Account retrieveAccount(String userId) {
    LdapQuery query = query().base("ou=users").where("uid").is(userId);
    List<Account> list = ldapTemplate.search(query,
            new AccountMapper());
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    return null;
}

public class AccountMapper implements
        AttributesMapper<Account> {

    @Override
    public Account mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs)
            throws NamingException {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setEmail((String) attrs.get("mail").get());
        account.setUserId((String) attrs.get("uid").get());

        return account;
    }
}
}
```

(Leaving out the Account class since it should be self explanatory.)

If I replace `mockLdapTemplate.search(query().base(anyString).where(anyString)
                        .is("userA"), (AttributesMapper) any);` with `mockLdapTemplate.search((LdapQuery)withNotNull(), (AttributesMapper) any)` the test passes (which is what I expect, but this more or less tells me the problem is with the LdapQuery parameter).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the answer: the expectation should be recorded as

```
mockLdapTemplate.search((LdapQuery)withNotNull(), (AttributesMapper) any)
```

because this is the only mocked method being called from the unit under test. The argument matchers "any", "withNotNull()", etc. can only be used on calls to *mocked* methods, and `LdapQuery` was not mocked in the test.

Comment: Okay. So I do need to mock LdapQuery?  Can you provide any example of that? My test is in the is() method when I pass in the "userA" parameter.  Essentially without that the test doesn't really test anything.

Comment: You could mock `LdapQuery`, but that would get complicated; a possible alternative (depending on the availability of suitable "getters" in the query object) would be to capture the query object passed to the `search` method, using `qry = withCapture()` as the argument matcher (with a local variable `LdapQuery qry`). Another alternative is to write an integration test using Spring's `org.springframework.ldap.test` facilities.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that first one a try.